# how to find 00 in date row and replace it in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Because I set `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` in sql_mode,I want to use

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_name 
 WHERE date_column regexp '[0-9]\d{4}-00-00' 
 order 
    by id
```

to find the `00-**` or `**-00` or `00-00` date column and replace the `00` to `01`.

But my script doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: Is it a date type column or datetime ? And you want to change `00-00-00` to `00-00-01` ? Later part does not make sense

Comment: date type column.I want to change `1980-00-00`,`1980-00-01`,`1980-01-00` to `1980-01-01`.

Comment: That regexp, if it works, checks for 5 digits at the start.  Perhaps you want `'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-00-00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date and time functions e.g. [DAYOFMONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) to extract the components of the date so that you can test them:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
 WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date_column) = 0 OR MONTH(date_column) = 0 
ORDER BY ID
```

You would need to convert the date to a string before you can match it against a regexp, and it's simpler to just test the date components directly.

Comment: This query will fail with error, because of `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` mode. it will throw out invalid datetime error. we need to use `set sql_mode = ''` before calling this, to remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` setting for a session locally.